# A facet wrapped, scales free, forest plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to produce a forest plot with facets in `R`, where the y axes are scale free. But I'm running into trouble.

Here's my example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10),x=c(1:5,1:3,1:2),group=c(rep("a",5),rep("b",3),rep("c",2)),name=c(paste("a",1:5,sep=""),paste("b",1:3,sep=""),paste("c",1:2,sep="")))
df$ymin <- df$y-runif(10,0.5,0.7)
df$ymax <- df$y+runif(10,0.5,0.7)
```

If I use :

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(y=y,x=x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))+geom_point()+coord_flip()+scale_y_discrete(limits=df$name)+facet_wrap(~group,ncol=3,scales="free")+geom_vline(lty=2,aes(xintercept=0,colour="black"))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in facet_render.wrap(plot$facet, panel, plot$coordinates, theme,  : 
  ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip.
```

Which has already been discussed on SO.

Trying to solve it by manually flipping the axes hence dropping the `flip_coord()` part, almost works - I'm not getting the error bars:

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(y=x,x=y,xmin=ymin,xmax=ymax))+geom_point()+scale_y_discrete(limits=df$name)+facet_wrap(~group,ncol=3,scales="free")+geom_vline(lty=2,aes(xintercept=0,colour="black"))
```

[image]

So my question is how do I get the errors bar on there?
Also, right now the y axes don't leave enough space below the bottom and above the top points. How do add a bit to each end so that the points are not cut off as they are now?

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

We can use `geom_segment` and set the `y` coordinate as `name`

```
p1 <- ggplot(df,aes(y = name, x = y))+
geom_point()+
facet_wrap(~group,ncol=3,scales="free")+
geom_segment(aes(x = ymin, xend = ymax, yend = name))+
geom_vline(lty=2, aes(xintercept=0), colour = 'red')

p1
```

[image]